# Program to repeat based on user input using nested loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a nested loop at the bottom of the main function, that if the user enters "y" the program will repeat, if "n" the function will return 0 and stop, and if the user enters some other letter give an error, to re-enter choice.

If I enter "y", the program repeats
If I enter "n", i get nothing just a blank like
If I enter "e" i get thrown into an infinite loop

```
int main() 
{

    //local constants
    const string ENTER_DAYS_RENTED = "Enter the number of days rented: ";
    const string ENTER_MILES_DRIVEN = "Enter number of miles driven: ";

    //local variables
    char userCarTypeChosen;
    char anotherBill;
    int daysRented;
    int milesDriven;
    double carCharge;
    double mileageCharge;
    double tax = 0;
    double total = 0;

    do 
    {
        //call function to display program description
        displayProgramDescription();

        //calls function to validate the car choice input by user
        userCarTypeChosen = validateCarChoice();

        //if car type chosen is suv (S) then only prompt will be to enter days
        //rented, if not prompt both days rented and miles driven.
        if (userCarTypeChosen == 'S')
        {
            daysRented = validateNumEntry(ENTER_DAYS_RENTED);
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {   
            daysRented = validateNumEntry(ENTER_DAYS_RENTED);
            cout << endl;
            milesDriven = validateNumEntry(ENTER_MILES_DRIVEN);
            cout << endl;
        }

        //blank lines between input and output
        cout << endl << endl;

        //calls function to calculate total car charge
        carCharge = calculateTotalCarCharge(userCarTypeChosen, daysRented);

        //calls function to calculate total mileage charge
        mileageCharge = calculateTotalMileageCharge(userCarTypeChosen, 
                        daysRented, milesDriven);

        calculateBillTotal(carCharge, mileageCharge, tax, total);

        printBill (userCarTypeChosen, daysRented, milesDriven, carCharge,
        mileageCharge, tax, total);

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Calculate another bill (y/n)? ";
        cin >> anotherBill;
        anotherBill = toupper(anotherBill);
        cout << endl;

    }
        while (anotherBill == 'Y');

            if (anotherBill !='N')
            cout << "Error - Calculate another bill (y/n)?" << endl;
            cin >> anotherBill;


    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:
created this function

```
char validateCalcNewBill()
{
    char billAgain;

    cout << "Calculate another bill (y/n)?";
    cin >> billAgain;
    cout << endl;
    billAgain = toupper(billAgain);

    while (billAgain != 'Y' && billAgain !='N')
    {
        cout<< "Error - Calculate another bill (y/n)?";
        cin >> billAgain;
        billAgain = toupper(billAgain);
    }

    return billAgain;
}
```

then at the end of main

```
//calls function to validate calculating a new bill
        anotherBill = validateCalcNewBill();

    }
        while (anotherBill == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should create a function, which asks for y/n input, and will repeat asking until it gets right input, and then return.

Comment: If you indent the last few lines properly (or rather, let your editor do it for you) you will notice a logical error there. It's also the reason for your problem (not an infinite loop, just your program stuck waiting for input).

Answer (score 0):

Try using while loop instead with an if-else statement to trap other answers.

```
char anotherBill = 'Y';

while (anotherBill != 'N')
{
    if(anotherBill == 'Y')
    {
        cout<<"Process...\n";

        cout<<"Calculate another bill? (y/n):";
        cin>>anotherBill;
        anotherBill = toupper(anotherBill);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Invalid input. Please re-enter:";
        cin>>anotherBill;
        anotherBill = toupper(anotherBill);
    }
}
```